# LinearLayout match_parent doesn't take other children's width into account?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to create a layout when I have an image, text aligned to the left of the layout.
and a chip aligned to the left.

[image]

I have tried this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/my_padding2"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/Icon"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:importantForAccessibility="no"
      tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      style="@style/ActionItemStyle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:ellipsize="end"
      android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
      android:maxLines="3"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
  <com.my.Chip
      android:id="@+id/highlight_chip"
      style="@style/Widget.Chip.Suggestive"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_highlight_chip_and_text"
      android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
      android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why does the textView's match_parent makes the chip's width to be 0dp?

I read about [match_parent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT):

> Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
>   MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
>   minus the parent's padding, if any. Introduced in API Level 8.

but does it ignores the siblings size?

I know I can use `weight`, but still want to understand: does `match_parent` ignore siblings' width?

[image]

Comment: Your parent LinearLayout has paddingLeft and paddingRight. Also, chip has marginStart and marginLeft given

Comment: textview did not make chips size 0dp but it covers all remaining portion so chip view is hidden.

Comment: @yuvrajsinh  but why is the chip 40dp width ignored?

Comment: @RahulKhurana still, the text `"match_parent"` ignores the chip's 40dp width?

Comment: if you will see your xml's preview you can see that chip view is showing outside the linear layout with its defined size

Comment: @EladBenda what is the design of your custom chip? Also, show the style code of `Widget.Chip.Suggestive`

Answer (score 0):

`match_parent` attribute reacts according to the Parent View. `LinearLayout`'s child view with width as `match_parent will take up the whole width and will not accommodate any further child view if orientation is horizontal as we are talking abour width.

For LinearLayout - To accommodate another child view along with child view having `match_parent`; you need to use `layout_weight`.

Though you can use another `ViewGroup` - `FrameLayout` without making use of `layout_weight`.

Below is the code using `FrameLayout` as Parent `ViewGroup`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/my_padding"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/my_padding"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/my_padding2"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/my_padding2"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/Icon"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
       android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
       android:contentDescription="@null"
       android:importantForAccessibility="no"
       tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/Text"
       style="@style/ActionItemStyle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"//give enough margin from your icon
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_between_icon_and_text"//give enough margin from your icon
       android:layout_marginRight="64dp"//give enough margin from your chip
       android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
       android:maxLines="3"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <com.my.Chip
       android:id="@+id/highlight_chip"
       style="@style/Widget.Chip.Suggestive"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"//give enough margin from right edge of screen
       android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
       android:visibility="visible" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have added to the chip `android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"` but the chip still get out of the frame

Comment: `LinearLayout` requires all the child view's to have `android:layout_weight` to proportionate according to weight. Just making Chip layout with android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" won't work. All the other view's - `TextView` & `ImageView` should also have weight & width as 0dp; that will make it proportionate, it's better to use `FrameLayout` in that case. Please try the solution; I have provided in the above answer.